# Alternative to workflowy - ToDo List (no cloud service)

Tags: productivity, todo

I'm searching for an alternative to [Workflowy](https://workflowy.com/). I think its one of the best toDo lists. However since I want to use it for professional data, I don't like to store it in a cloud service. A desktop or self hosted alternative would be fine too.

Requierements:

- Hirachical ToDo List
- Breadcrumb Bar navigation
- Hashtags itmes for filtering and searching
- Windows Desktop app w/o need to store data in cloud.

Not required, but nice to have:

- Possibility to add longer text to the individual items
- Keeping a journal of all changes

Comment: Welcome aboard; although you have already accepted an answer, I would remind you - and others - that for future questions, when asking for a desktop solution, it is helpful if you specify an  operating system - not everyone runs MacOs :-)  Also, if you are willing to pay, please state a budget, else I might recommend a perfect match costing $10k+. If you want it free, use the [tag:gratis] tag. That should all be covered in [ask]. No offence intended, this is as much for future readers as for you; please give us as much info as you can, so that we can better help you. welcome on board :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [myTinyTodo](http://www.mytinytodo.net/). Apart from breadcrumb navigation it seems to fit what you are looking for.

Another one I found is [Planz](http://kftf.ischool.washington.edu/planner_index.htm) but it might be a bit overkill, functionality-wise.

Comment: Thank you for the hint to Planz. This is pretty cool. I think this will be my new favourit task organizer.

Comment: No problem! Happy to have helped.

Comment: After playing around with Planz I found out that it has some weaknesses. As mentioned  in the help version 8.2 is just a prototype and not a final product. Additionally there has no maintainace done since 2010. Seems the project is dead. It's a bitty.